# EPERM Error in NodeJS for window shared folder

Tags: node.js

I am trying to copy a local file to shared folder but EPERM error is showing. This is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var is = fs.createReadStream(SOURCE_FILE);
var os = fs.createWriteStream(TARGET_FILE);

is.pipe(os);
is.on('end', function() {
    console.log('success');
});
```

... this is the error message:
*Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: EPERM, open 'TARGET_FILE'*

TARGET_FILE includes a windows shared folder with all permissions for all users

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are running IISNODE on IIS 7/8 it could be running on a special type of user that does not inherit "All Users" permission.

If you are running iisnode from a command prompt it is probably running as the user you are logged in as.  If you are running it in a service wrapper it is probably also running under a a "user" that does not inherit "All Users" permission.  You can load the task manager (right click on your task bar) to see what user the process is running under.

If you are using IISNODE in IIS, node.js is using the same user as the domain you are running it under.  Typically DefaultAppPool.

TO give DefaultAppPool permission:

1. right click on the folder
2. select properties
3. select the security tab
4. click the edit button
5. click the add button
6. enter **IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool** in the box (including spaces)
7. click the check names button
8. it should now show DefaultAppPool underlined, click OK
9. select DefaultAppPool from the list of users and assign them the minimum required rights - resist the temptation to give DefaultAppPool excessive rights.